# When in mobile emulation (using Ionic in Chrome browser) date input behaves strangely

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, ionic-framework

I have the following element in my Ionic app:

```
<input type="date"
       ng-model="input.startDate"
       class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched"
       style="">
```

In chrome (mobile emulation mode) this input gets a drop down arrow, when I click on it I get the following date picker:

[image]

If I display the same page without mobile emulation, date picker displays correctly, is there something I'm doing wrong or is this a Chrome bug?

I'm using **Chrome version 48.0.2564.48 beta-m (64-bit)**

***Edit:*** I noticed I was on beta channel, don't know when that happened, I changed to stable but the problem persists (on **Chrome Version 48.0.2564.48 m (64-bit)**).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem and i found that if u put the Device pixel ratio on 1 the date picker will show as normal.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use **GapDebug** , https://www.genuitec.com/products/gapdebug/
it's better that emulate with chrome.